# MySQL, PHP Using LIKE Syntax?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a user search with the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../BD/bd.php");

$searched_for = $_POST['searched_for'];
$query = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_media WHERE nombre LIKE '%$searched_for%'") or die(mysql_error());

while($got_users = @mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo '<div class="searched-content-info">'.
         '<div class="searched-photo"><img src="'.$got_users['foto'].'"></div>
         <div class="searched-names"><h3>'.$got_users['nombre'].'</h3></div>
         <div class="searched-dates"><h3>'.'Miembro desde: '.$got_users['created_on'].'</h3></div>  
         </div> 
         <div class="divisor-search-user"></div>';
}

?>
```

But I'm getting all the rows, I just want to display the searched users info, seems like the `$query` is receiving a clean `$searched_for`

Any help here? Btw, I'm a little newbie here, please don't bully :)

EDIT: I tried changing `$got_users['nombre'];` with `$searched_for` to see if `$searched_for` is empty and yes it doesn't return any string that's why I am getting all the rows. `$query` is getting an empty variable but Why?

Here's my HTML:

```
<form target="u-n" id="search_input" action="search_user.php" method="post">
    <input id="search-input" name="searched_for" type="search" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Don't even know where to start here...

Comment: try to change `$searched_for = $_POST['searched_for'];` to `$searched_for = $_REQUEST['searched_for'];` and then google about SQL injections

Comment: Check the name of the field `searched_for` in your form. Check cases.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO. Start debug by removing all error suppressing `@`.

Comment: *sidenote:* your code is subjected to SQL Injection attack, as you directly allow POST values to be inserted in your query.

Comment: You suppress all the errors with `@`, then wonder why you don't know what's wrong....

Comment: Also, where is your HTML structure? DOCTYPE, head, body, etc?

Comment: Shivan this content loads inside a 'div' on profile.php

Comment: do you still have the problem? if yes then can you tell em clearly how your result is?i mean are you getting all searched_for values?

Comment: feroz akbar I tried changing $got_users['nombre']; with $searched_for to see if $searched_for is empty and yes it doesn't return any string that's why I am getting all the rows. $query is getting an empty variable but Why?

Answer (score 1):

You used `<input type="search" />` which is a HTML5 feature. Older browsers may not support this. Replace this input with `type="text"`.

Then, your `$_POST['searched_for']` should populate properly, that is:

```
<input name="searched_for" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
```

Also, you used the same `id` multiple times, which is an invalid HTML syntax.

Reference: [HTML input tag at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)